# Can't convert string column into float

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to train a linear regression model in jupyter notebooks and loaded an csv file created via Google Sheets. All the data was saved as number in the sheet, but when i loaded the CSV into Jupyter it is turned into an string and i can't convert it back, it gives the following error: could not convert string to float: '10.801.68'

[image: A sample from the DataFrame]

Already changed the commas by dots and tried the following code:

```
df.columns=['Data', 'Price', 'Volume']
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.replace(',','.')
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(float)
```

Comment: Please post a textual representation of the dataframe, not a picture. Also, post an excerpt of the CSV you're tring to parse.

Comment: Try replacing with empty spaces `df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.replace(',','')`

Comment: What dtype is your `Price` column?

Comment: what should be the float value of '10.801.68' ? there are tow dots, in a number there should be only one dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the . from your '10.801.68' as Yatu said: `df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.replace(',','')`, or try to change the thousand seperator while reading your csv file, for example:
`pd.read_csv(thousands=r'.')`

Your number format in your csv files (saved on windows I would assume) is quite different to python logic, I would try to adjust it directly in the reading process.

Comment: Thank you, that extra dot was the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do as PV8 suggested within python or clean the file withing excel by replacing (ctrl+h) '.' with ''